# Kohana 3.2 : Error reading session data

Tags: session, kohana, authentication

I'm working on a module (a simple cms) with Kohana 3.2 and i'm getting this exception "Error reading session data."

I'm using native session and the funny thing is if i set a "default" group database connection the error isn't showed... (i'm using a custom connection group and i've set this database connection group to the user,role and user_token models).

here's my config file

auth.php

```
return array(

    'driver'       => 'orm',
    'hash_method'  => 'sha256',
    'hash_key'     => 'just a test 1',
    'lifetime'     => 1209600,
    'session_type' => 'native',
    'session_key'  => 'just a test 2',

    // Username/password combinations for the Auth File driver

    'users' => array(
       // 'luca' => 'e12afe0d3ead3d36191d86229d27057d96d9f2e063fe6f3e86699aaab5310d42'
        // 'admin' => 'b3154acf3a344170077d11bdb5fff31532f679a1919e716a02',
    ),

);
```

session.php

```
return array(
    'native' => array(
        'name' => 'session_native',
        'lifetime' => 43200,
    ),
    'cookie' => array(
        'name' => 'session_cookie',
        'encrypted' => TRUE,
        'lifetime' => 43200,
    ),
    'database' => array(
        'name' => 'session_database',
        'encrypted' => TRUE,
        'lifetime' => 43200,
        'group' => Pencil::db_group(),
        'table' => 'sessions',
        'columns' => array(
            'session_id'  => 'session_id',
            'last_active' => 'last_active',
            'contents'    => 'contents'
        ),
        'gc' => 500,
    ),
);
```

Comment: i found that forcing Kohana_ORM->_db_group to my custom database group  i solved the problem but this isn't a decent solution for me.

Comment: I had a similiar problem with session data. Are you sure, that variable `$_SESSION` and function `session_start()` is being used somewhere? Do a text search.

Answer (score 0):

You set encrypted to true, so you need an encrypt key.  In your config/encrypt.php add this:

```
  <?php

return array(
    'default' => array(
        'key' => 'MY_RANDOM_KEY_I_MADE_UP_ALL_BY_MYSELF',
    ),
);
```

I would keep session_key set to 'auth_user' instead of your random key as well.  I think key in that circumstance is not the same as a hash key.

Check your logs in application/logs to see if anything else is missing.